# How to integrate Metaphone to the spellchecker program in java-lucene?

Tags: java, lucene, metaphone

While browsing i came up with a spellchecking program in lucene.I was interested in adding the phonetix add-on(specifically metaphone) from tangentum. Is there a way i can integrate metaphone into my program? How to integrate it?

```
package com.lucene.spellcheck;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.Dictionary;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.PlainTextDictionary;
import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
public class SimpleSuggestionService {
private static final String F_WORD = null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
File dir = new File("e:/spellchecker/");
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(dir);
SpellChecker spellChecker1 = new SpellChecker(directory);
spellChecker1.indexDictionary(
new PlainTextDictionary(new File("c:/fulldictionary00.txt")));
String wordForSuggestions = "noveil";
int suggestionsNumber = 5;
String[] suggestions = spellChecker1.
suggestSimilar(wordForSuggestions, suggestionsNumber);
if (suggestions!=null && suggestions.length>0) {
for (String word : suggestions) {
System.out.println("Did you mean:" + word);
}
}
else {
System.out.println("No suggestions found for word:"+wordForSuggestions);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in a custom [StringDistance](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/StringDistance.html) implementation that utilizes desired phonetic algorithms, or combines it is some way with other similarity algorithms (such as the standard [LevensteinDistance](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/LevensteinDistance.html).  You'll just need to implement the getDistance(String, String) method in you StringDistance implementation.  Perhaps something like:

```
public MetaphoneDistance() {
    Metaphone metaphone = new Metaphone();
}

//I'm not really familiar with the library you mentioned, but I assume generateKeys performs a double metaphone?
public float getDistance(String str1, ,String str2) {
    String[] keys1 = metaphone.getKeys(str1);  
    String[] keys2 = metaphone.getKeys(str2);
    float result = 0;
    if (key1[0] == key2[0] || key1[0] == key2[1]) result += .5
    if (key1[1] == key2[0] || key1[1] == key2[1]) result += .5
    return result;
}
```